# How pkmap_page_table is used on kmap?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, mmu

pkmap_page_table has a pointer of page table for kmap when kernel starts.
For example, PKMAP_BASE is 0xFFE00000 and FIXADDR_START is 0xFFF00000, if kernel tries to use the high memory, TTB0's PTE should be set to 0xFFE00000 ~ 0xFFF00000 for virtual address.
Then how pkmap_page_table's PTE is used to making map?
And how TTB0's PTE is modified as same with pkmap_page_table's PTE?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not actually sure about that what problem occuring with you but there some code sinnpet availble in "Understading the Linux Kernel" book.

On the [page 309](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=h0lltXyJ8aIC&pg=PT327&lpg=PT327&dq=pkmap_page_table&source=bl&ots=gN5qJ-7bKW&sig=VuWurreevrORcWqOQie0tcIX0AA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qaNjUfeKHoqQrge1_ICAAQ&redir_esc=y); last lines; "Once the procress is awakened the function checks that whether the another process has mapped the page by invoking `page_address()`; if no other process has mapped the page yet the inner loop restarted."